# How to center title over SVG chart with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, text-align

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/29j6ozqn/

I've created a simple SVG with two axes and appended a `text` element to serve as the title of the chart. But I can't find a reliable way to center the title over the midpoint of the chart. I'd like the **middle of the text element** to be aligned over the '0.5' tick on the x-axis. To me, visually, that's the middle of the chart.

I'd like a solution that is generic, meaning it doesn't matter how long the text string is, the middle will always be over '0.5'. It also shouldn't matter what type of axis the x-axis is (whether it's linear, ordinal, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `text-anchor: middle` or `text-align: center` instead of `text-anchor: start`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/wz514fdn/5/).

Comment: Ah, wow...that's what I get for mindlessly copying CSS without looking at it.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)